# Long boot times on fresh install, timed out waiting for device

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, partitioning, fstab

I am getting really long boot times (circa 5 minutes) on a fresh install on a fresh HDD.

I think the culprit is `systemd` looking for a device that doesn't exist, namely the original HDD on this laptop. After my original HDD started giving a whole lot of errors, I plugged in a new one as an external one, and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. In the process, the new Ubuntu installation was apparently set up with two "devices" to look for.

The error is the following:

> systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b28e5fc\x2d1e5c\x2d43f3\x2d8875\x2d82a3509707b6.device: Job dev-disk-x2d82a3509707b6.device/start timed out.
>
> systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b28e5fc\x2d1e5c\x2d43f3\x2d8875\x2d82a35\x2d82a3509707b6.device.
>
> systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/9b28e5fc-1e5c-43f3-8875-82a3509707b6.
>
> systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b28e5fc\x2d1e5c\x2d43f3\x2d8875\x2d82a3509707b6.swap: Job dev-disk-by x2d82a3509707b6.swap/start failed with result 'dependency'.
>
> systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9b28e5fc\x2d1e5c\x2d43f3\x2d8875\x2d82a3509707b6.device: Job dev-disk-`x2d82a3509707b6.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.

I checked `/etc/fstab/` and sure enough there were two swap partitions listed there, one in sda2, and one in sdb2. I removed the line for sda2, but the error and slow load times persist.